# C Sockets: Avoiding garbage when socket is closed

Tags: c, sockets, networking, select, winsock2

I'm programming a server and a client using non blocking sockets (`fd_sets` and `select` function) and once the server closes or shuts down a client socket, the client starts receiving a lot of garbage until it crashes..
I've been warned that when working with `select()` a socket would become readable when the connection was terminated, but how can I know in

```
if( FD_ISSET( socket, &read ) ) 
{
}
```

if the cause is just regular data or the connection has ended?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file descriptor sets wont tell you if the socket is closed, only that you may attempt to read from it. When the remote end closes the connection the socket will become "readable". When you attempt a `recv()` the return value will be 0 indicating the socket is closed. Always check your return values.

Comment: Thanks! So, recv() returns 0 when socket is closed? Haha, that was so obvious.. thanks a lot

Comment: @Lucas Hi ! Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you are satisfied with Dave's answer, you are encouraged to accept it, and maybe upvoting it. Cheers !

Comment: Thanks! I've signed up and I'll be able to vote answers as soon as I get some rep points

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `poll` instead (it's also more flexible because it's not bound by the size of FD_SET!)

```
struct poll p = {.fd = fd, .events = POLLHUP|POLLRDHUP};
```